# Remove "Name" field from Event record page

Tags: page-layout

How do I remove the "Name" field on "Event" record pages? We link Event records using the WhoId field to both Contacts and Users. The Name field doesn't link to User records.

I've seen there is a field named "Attendees" which allows me to link both Contacts and Users, however I can't seem to remove the Name field from the Event record page. It doesn't make any sense to have both fields on the page layout.

The other option is relabel the Attendees field, but I seem to be faced with the problem of not being able to do this, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we cannot remove the 'Name' field on 'Event' record pages at this time.

Coming to renaming the Attendees field, I came across this [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001Jid3QAC) logged recently which I believe is relevant to what you have described in your question. To subscribe for updates on this bug, I recommend clicking "This Issue Affects me" button